# How can I find out why Android Auto in developer mode won't connect to the "Desktop Head Unit"?

Tags: android-studio, android-auto

I am attempting to get car_app_library hello world example to run through android auto to the DHU.

I have two different workstations with Android Studio and the DHU 2.0Beta. I have two different Android Devices, a Galaxy S9+ and a Galaxy Tab S6.

With any combination, with ADB and DHU running, locally on the devices at best, I can get a full white screen to flash which disappears, and no connection from there.

On the device, I have enabled unknown sources in Android Auto, and I have started "Head Unit Server"

On the workstation, DHU simply indicates at all times, "Waiting for phone...".

Studio "Run" indicates "success, operation succeeded" but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working after two days. I could tell when it was not working that 1/5 times I'd see a flashed screen prompting for bluetooth and to continue, but I could not click any buttons in time.

Finally,

1. I uninstalled the "Android Auto for phones" application on the device, and I think this was the real solution
2. I also moved to canary channel for studio, and then needed to uninstall and reinstall the desktop head unit.

After this, I could get the screen to show that I saw flashing before, and I had to accept it once, then it crashed again, then I started it all again, and it is finally working.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70864572/8956715