# Android Auto DHU failed to connect to android emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-auto

I tried to connected Android Auto DHU r1.1 in windows with the Android Emulator in Android Studio，but got this error.
In emulator:
[Communication error 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s8pL.png).

In desktop head unit:

> Shutting down connection due to authentication failure.

I have checked the time, time zone and got the newest android auto.

Answer (score 1):

1. `adb forward tcp:5277 tcp:5277` (set adb proper port)
2. Stop head unit -> Start head unit (on the phone)
3. Launch `desktop-head-unit.exe`

and read https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing#running-dhu

Work fine for me